# How to auto-generate objects in the Register Model C# ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I using the Internet Application template in C# MVC 4 which generates the `Account` model and controller for you in Visual Studio. This gives me basic form functionality for logging in. I modified the `Register` class in the `Account` model to also take a `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Email` in addition to the username and password. My table with user information is `Users`. When a user submits their information `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);`
is ran and it adds the `Username` to my Users table. So at that point I have my PK `Id` and `Username` in the table. My `User` class definition has a custom object `Portfolio`. What I am trying to do is when the user registers they get added to the table and then I find that `User` and set the values for the rest of the data in the table and instantiate the `Portfolio` object. This would complete my register process.Currently, it adds the user to the table with just the `Username` adds them to the role and redirects back to index. My var user = `_db.Users.Find(userId)` is apparently not finding anything for some reason. I even tried to cheat and hardcode the `userId` because I knew what the next `Id` would be in the `Users` table and it still did not modify the table values. `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email` all remain null in the table and no object is instantiated for `Portfolio`. I have my context so it should work. I did something similar in my `Seed` method and it worked fine. I am not sure why it is not working here. Does anyone have suggestions? Thank you.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, TeamProject.Models.ProjectDb2 context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

                var userId = _db.Users
                             .Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName)
                             .Select(u => u.Id).First();
                var user = _db.Users.Find(userId);
                user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                user.LastName = model.LastName;
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.Portfolio = new Portfolio
                {
                    Stocks = new List<Stock>
                    {
                    }
                };
                context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);

                System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Users");
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Comment: You do not appear to be calling `context.SaveChanges` anywhere.

Comment: If it was a snake, it would have bit me. I did something similar in Seed() but you don't have do `SaveChanges` there. Thank you that fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above comment:

> You do not appear to be calling context.SaveChanges anywhere.

Comment: Marked as answer for you. Appreciate it!